# Apply metric tag from request header globally in SpringBoot with Micrometer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway, micrometer, spring-micrometer

We have an app currently using spring cloud gateway, and we need to add a request header to every metric globally, which was easy enough for the out of the box metrics from the framework. The problem comes when we want to add our own custom metrics. None of the globally added tags are sent. This is my config:

```
@Configuration
public class MetricsConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebFluxTagsContributor webFluxTagsContributor() {
        return (exchange, ex) -> buildRequestTags(exchange);
    }

    @Bean
    public GatewayTagsProvider requestTagsProvider() {
        return exchange -> buildRequestTags(exchange);
    }

    @NotNull
    private Tags buildRequestTags(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
        String clientApplication = HeadersUtils.get(serverWebExchange.getRequest().getHeaders(), "X-$%$#%$#");
        return Tags.of(Tag.of(MetricTag.APP_FROM.lowered(), clientApplication));
    }
}
```

And this is where my custom metric is added:

```
@Component
public class ProviderRoutesHeaderFilter implements WebFilter, Ordered {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProviderRoutesHeaderFilter.class);

    public static final String A_HEADER_KEY = "x-*&%^";

    private final MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

    public ProviderRoutesHeaderFilter(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        this.meterRegistry = meterRegistry;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return -2;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        var request = exchange.getRequest();
        if(request.getPath().toString().contains("/someroute/") && !request.getHeaders().containsKey(A_HEADER_KEY)) {
            traceUnspecifiedHeader(request);
            return chain.filter(exchange.mutate()
                                        .request(request.mutate()
                                                        .header(A_HEADER_KEY, NOT_SPECIFIED.name())
                                                        .build())
                                        .build());

        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }

    private void traceUnspecifiedHeader(ServerHttpRequest request) {
        LOG.info(A_HEADER_KEY + " header not specified... applying default header");
        Set<Tag> tags = Collections.singleton(Tag.of(MetricTag.PATH.lowered(), request.getPath().value()));
        meterRegistry.counter("sp.gateway.a_not_specified", tags).increment();
    }
}
```

With this setup I can see the tag in the request metrics:

**localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/spring.cloud.gateway.requests**

```
{
    "name": "spring.cloud.gateway.requests",
    "description": null,
    "baseUnit": "milliseconds",
    "measurements": [
        {
            "statistic": "COUNT",
            "value": 1.0
        },
        {
            "statistic": "TOTAL_TIME",
            "value": 698.241891
        },
        {
            "statistic": "MAX",
            "value": 0.0
        }
    ],
    "availableTags": [
        {
            "tag": "routeUri",
            "values": [
                "http://www.***.com:80"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "routeId",
            "values": [
                "******"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "httpMethod",
            "values": [
                "GET"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "app_from",
            "values": [        -----> this is my tag
                "andy"
            ] 
        },
        {
            "tag": "outcome",
            "values": [
                "CLIENT_ERROR"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "status",
            "values": [
                "BAD_REQUEST"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "httpStatusCode",
            "values": [
                "400"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But not in my custom metric:
**localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/sp.gateway.a_not_specified**

```
{
    "name": "sp.gateway.a_not_specified",
    "description": null,
    "baseUnit": null,
    "measurements": [
        {
            "statistic": "COUNT",
            "value": 2.0
        }
    ],
    "availableTags": [
        {
            "tag": "path",
            "values": [
                "/pr****/***/**"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there some config I am missing to accomplish this?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add the same tags used by the framework by hooking in the filter *after* the request has been handled and use the same tag provider as used by `spring.cloud.gateway.requests` and expose your custom tag as a static method.

Maybe you can use the `doFinally` method on the `Mono`, something like this (I have not tested if it works)

```java
  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    return chain.filter(exchange)
        .doFinally(signalType -> {
          Set<Tag> tags = Collections.singleton(Tag.of(MetricTag.PATH.lowered(), exchange.getRequest().getPath().value()));
          tags.addAll(new GatewayHttpTagsProvider().apply(exchange).stream().toList());
          tags.add(buildRequestTags(exchange));
          meterRegistry.counter("sp.gateway.a_not_specified", tags).increment();
    });
  }
```